# how to get ip address in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ip-address

I am doing this following code for login attempt & i want get IP address of my local machine..

```
if ( !$this->session->userdata('login_attempts') )
{
   $this->session->set_userdata('login_attempts', 0);
}
$attempts = ($this->session->userdata('login_attempts') + 1);
$this->session->set_userdata('login_attempts', $attempts);
// Check if the session.
if ( $this->session->userdata('login_attempts') > 4 )
{
    echo 'hi....login attempt is over';
}
// Failed. So, update the session    

echo $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
// $ip_address = $this->input->ip_address1();
// return $ip_address;
echo $this->input->ip_address();
if ( ! $this->input->valid_ip($ip))
{
    echo 'Not Valid';
}
else
{
    echo 'Valid';
}
$this->db->update('loginattempts',array( 'login_attempts' =>$this->session->userdata('login_attempts') , 'lastLogin' =>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),'ip'=>$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ),array('login_id' =>1) );
echo ('hi....login attempt is'.$this->session->userdata('login_attempts'));

}
```

but it show incorrect ip address of my local machine.

Comment: Are you really looking for the IP address of your local machine, or of the user trying to connect?

Answer (score 85):

Use `$this->input->ip_address()`

```
$ip = $this->input->ip_address();
```

- [Codeigniter 2 - Input Class: ip_address()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::ip_address)
- [CodeIgniter 3 - Input Class: ip_address()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::ip_address)

Or in CI4: `$this->request->getIPAddress()`

```
$ip = $this->request->getIPAddress();
```

- [CodeIgniter 4 - Request Class: getIPAddress()](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/request.html#getIPAddress)

Answer (score 4):

To get the remote IP address, in PHP, you could use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, CodeIgniter is doing the same thing behind the scenes.

Comment: Codeigniter is not doing that, but [more](https://github.com/wildlyinaccurate/CodeIgniter-2-with-Doctrine-2/blob/master/system/core/Input.php#L311).

Answer (score 1):

use anyone from below .. same like $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']

$_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']
```

We should use codeigniter function for security,
we should use `$this->input->ip_address();` , This will give client ip

If you want to access server variable use like this

```
$this->input->server(array('HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')));
```

For reference please have a look 
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use on an external service if you trust that it will have 100% uptime.

```
$ip = file_get_contents('https://api.ipify.org');
```